# Why is $\frac{1}{2}ie^{-iw-iz}-\frac{1}{2}ie^{iw+iz}=\sin(w+z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying for a while now and I don't see the stes. I know that:$$\sin(z+w)=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i(z+w)}-e^{-i(z+w)}\right)$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{i}=-i$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

All you have to do is to replace $1/i$ with $-i$ and you get your formula.

Comment: understood, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The given equality comes from Euler's Identity 
$$ \exp(i\theta) = cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$ and the parity of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ ($\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$). This identity is super helpful in calculating all the angle addition formulas from trigonometry. The proof of Euler's identity comes from the Taylor expansion of $\exp(z)$ and the fact that this series is convergent for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Setting $\theta = z+w$ and expanding the exponentials on the left hand side of the equality gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2i}\left[ \exp(i\theta)-\exp(-i\theta)\right] & = \frac{1}{2i}\left[ \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)-\cos(-\theta)-i\sin(-\theta)\right] \\
 & = \frac{1}{2i}\left[ \cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\right] \\
& = \frac{1}{2i}\left[ 2i\sin(\theta)\right] =\sin(\theta).
\end{align}
$$
This is exactly the equality you were looking for.

Comment: Why wouldn't it hold for complex $w, z$ too? The difference between the two sides is by any means holomorphic, _so_ if it is $0$ for real $w,z$ it has to be $0$ everywhere by the identity theorem.

Comment: You're right- thanks! (I shouldn't be doing any thinking on Saturday mornings)